# Forcing output text to a hyper link

Tags: excel, vba

So i am working on an application to be used with/inside excel and i have some check boxes that put out predetermined verbiage. I need when out put said verbiage to be a hyperlink BUT i don't want all things put out in that cell to be a hyperlink. I found this code below and to me (knows very little about code etc) and it seems like its what i want it to do, BUT i am not sure. Basically i am looking to have visit out website <-- that would be the hyperlink go to the address it needs to. Is there a way to force something to a hyperlink by identifying say website or http if needed?

' Written by: Michael Milette
' Copyright 2011-2012 TNG Consulting Inc.
' Purpose: Converts the selected text into hyperlinks.
' Note: HTTP is assumed if not specified in the text.

```
`Public Sub Text_To_Hyperlink()
  Dim Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Trim(Cell) > "" Then
      If Left(Trim(Cell), 4) = "http" Then  ' handles http and https
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell, Trim(Cell.Value)
      Else ' Default to http if no protocol was specified.
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell, "http://" & Trim(Cell.Value)
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub`
```

I have pre determined verbiage and can get a hyper link to format in the excel sheet but once the VBA code is introduced it forces it back to text

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub addhyperlink()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If Trim(Cell) > "" Then
            If Left(Trim(Cell), 4) = "http" Then ' handles http and https
                ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:=Trim(Cell.Value), _
                                          SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
            Else ' Default to http if no protocol was specified.
                ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:="http://" & Trim(Cell.Value), _
                                          SubAddress:="", TextToDisplay:=Cell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to your code, but maybe the HYPERLINK formula would work for your stated problem.

In C3 use this formula `=HYPERLINK(B2,A2)`

[image]

Comment: i've tried this, the moment my script runs to output said verbiage based on chosen boxes it forces the hyperlink to just text.